# substitutes for vertically scrolling through a large list

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I am envisioning a Google Glass knitting app to help my sister. Many knitters, including her, like to work from knitting charts, which are big grids with special symbols to indicate the type of stitch. You work your way down the chart, one row at a time, knitting the indicated stitches, and voila! you have a fancy sweater or whatever. She often knits while sitting on the bus, or even while walking, and having the chart on Glass would leave her hands free to do what's important.

Let me describe the ideal, but apparently unsupported, interface, and then you can tell me if there's any good substitute. Ideally, there would be a bundle containing 100 numbered rows of knitting symbols (or however long the chart is). The user sees the current row across the middle of the screen, with the rows above and below displayed more dimly. Swiping back and forward would move up and down the chart, vertically scrolling by one row and highlighting the current row. Because there are so many rows, the user needs a way to skip to a particular row, if they are picking up where they left off. I imagine them tapping to bring up a menu that allows them to speak the desired row number.

It appears that this is completely impossible at the moment. Vertical scrolling is not supported; instead, I would need to create a bundle of horizontally scrolling images of sets of three rows, with the one in the middle highlighted to be the "current" one. OK, that's an acceptable substitute. But then how does the user select a particular row? Do I need to give each card a menu allowing them to somehow request a particular row, which then gets sent over the network to the server, which then sends back a new version of the bundle with the desired row toward the beginning? That sounds wasteful, slow and fragile. Does the Glass UI provide any way to handle this kind of data? If not, is it possible that it will handle it in the future?

I can imagine plenty of applications (teleprompter, karaoke, etc.) that involve vertically scrolling through significant numbers of rows, so I'm sure I'm not the only requester of this, which makes me think that maybe, if it's not currently supported, it might be in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are interested in filing a feature request with the Glass team. You can do so [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) by clicking the New Issue button in the top left. In your request, it will be helpful to the Glass team to summarize the use case that you have described in this question.